# What is the farthest commercial flight on a B737-800 currently?

Tags: commercial-aviation, boeing-737

Can anybody name the airline, distance and respective city pair of the farthest (not necessarily longest) nonstop flight on a Boeing B737-800 (currently or in the past)? I'm not interested in empty delivery or ferry flights, but in revenue, commercial flights with this aircraft type.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is GOL's Orlando->Brasilia flight at 3,778 miles. Prior to that it was Newburgh to Bergen at 3,456 miles.

Lufthansa has a 737-700 but it is a Boeing Business jet equipped with extra fuel tanks and only 86 seats which makes a Frankfurt to Pune 4,158 mile flight.

[Source](https://thepointsguy.com/2018/01/gol-airlines-nonstop-flights-us-worlds-longest-737-route/)

Comment: Thank you! Actually, Lufthansa 's flight to Pune was operated by Privatair and was discontinued in July. Beginning November 1st, they will use an LH A319 in this route, making a fuel stop in Baku each way. https://onemileatatime.com/lufthansa-is-launching-the-worlds-worst-flight/